# Sort by distinct Stream API

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a following `JourneyType` class

```
public class JourneyType {

    private String hostId;

}
```

and a method

```
public void getHotsId(List<JourneyType> journeyTypeList) {      
    journeyTypeList.stream().map(p -> p.getHostId()).distinct().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());      
}
```

Filter class I have already did stream. So I would like to sort by hostId. I am stuck, any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sort the stream of `JourneyType` by a `getHostId()` method result you can supply your own `Comparator`

```
List<JourneyType> res = journeyTypeList.stream()
  .sorted(Comparator.comparing(JourneyType::getHostId))
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If your objective is just to sort the original collection it's easier to use `Collections` class:

```
Collections.sort(journeyTypeList, Comparator.comparing(JourneyType::getHostId));
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir, so Do ı need to do anything else on inside that method ? to be able to sort

Comment: @phantasma your code is currently ignoring the result of the stream operation, it's impossible to tell what are you trying to do.